Upgraded to Xcode16 and now keep seeing this when trying to build code BoringSSL-GRPC unsupported option '-G' for target 'arm64-apple-ios15.0'
since upgrading to Xcode 16 I have been getting this error. I have tried updating the Pod file below as many have suggested but when doing this it seems to break the link to all of my Pods and can not find any module for example I then get the error "No such module 'FirebaseUI'".
I have tried uninstalling and installing Pods, clearing the cache and clearing the derived data folders.
Not sure what else to try but my pod file currently looks like the below
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '15.0'

target 'Beauty Board' do
  use_frameworks!

  # Firebase dependencies
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
  pod 'FirebaseAnalytics'    # Core is now deprecated, use FirebaseAnalytics for
  pod 'FirebaseDatabase'
  pod 'FirebaseAuth'
  pod 'FirebaseFirestore'
  pod 'FirebaseStorage'
  pod 'FirebaseUI/Storage'
  pod 'FirebaseMessaging'
  pod 'FirebaseFirestoreSwift'
  pod 'FirebaseRemoteConfig'
  
  # Other dependencies
  pod 'SDWebImage'
  pod 'BoringSSL-GRPC'

  post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        # Set deployment target to 15.0
        #config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '15.0'
        # config.build_settings['EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]'] = 'arm64'
        
        if target.name == 'BoringSSL-GRPC'
          target.build_phases.each do |build_phase|
            build_phase.files.each do |file|
              if file.settings && file.settings['COMPILER_FLAGS']
                flags = file.settings['COMPILER_FLAGS'].split
                # Remove unsupported flag '-G'
                flags.reject! { |flag| flag == '-G' }
                file.settings['COMPILER_FLAGS'] = flags.join(' ')
              end
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end

  target 'Beauty BoardTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'Beauty BoardUITests' do
    # Pods for testing
  end

end

